# what is this? bash shows rectangular colored filled area

Tags: linux, bash, konsole

I just have seen that (see picture) and I'm wondering what I see there.

It's a little script, showing the status of a SAP server, which is executed by "watch"-cmd in a tmux-box.
When I move with the mouse over the word "GREEN", bash shows me a green filled area.

What kind of function is that? How is it named, configured, where is it part of?

[image: bash script showing the word GREEN and a green filled area]

I've done a little internet search that gave me no result

OK, it's from the konsole Terminal Emulator of KDE. And it shows some more colours as well, but I have no idea what's the use of it.

[image: yellow area]

Comment: Sounds more like a function of your terminal program than anything else.

Comment: OK, i've check some things.
It's not from tmux or the watch cmd. That green area is showed also when i execute the script just ones and move the mouse over the displayed text.

Comment: Then it's something from https://konsole.kde.org/ ?

Comment: this should be on [su] or [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 1):

Konsole is quite smart, it has integrated many things. In this case, when hovering curses over some text it is showing you the color of that text, so YELLOW shows a yellow box.

> What kind of function is that? How is it named, configured, where is it part of?

You would have to browse KDE konsole source code for that.

Comment: So it's nothing more then a useless gimmick, funny to see but no real usage for it?
Or can you create GUI-Elements or something with it? Any purpose?

Comment: I do not understand. The real usage is to see the color. You can do anything with it. It _is_ a gui element already, it's part of konsole gui.